# Cookie control via Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have to check from my web application if the browser cookie settings are enabled. If cookies are disabled, I have to throw an warning message.

I want to introduce this check during a page load.

Is there a way where I can check the browser settings via Javascript ? Or can you please suggest some other solution here ?

I want to do this activity on Chrome, Safari and IE atleast.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What I did once is this: set test cookie, read it. If it's not there throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `navigator.cookieEnabled` - set false when cookies are disabled on Safari and Chrome at least.